# Are these functions and parameters used in DirectX 11.2?

Tags: directx, directx11

Functions and parameters like WINAPI, hPrevInstance, hInstance , PSTR etc are used in DirectX 11.2?

Comment: Some of those are calling conventions, some are types, some are canonical parameters names. What exactly are you asking about here, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Direct3D 11.2 and the rest of the DirectX API's are based on COM interfaces, which does not use the Win32 API directly for their interfaces. **But!**

In order to create a context for D3D11, to handle mouse/keyboard input etc., DirectX needs to know which window you are using and which window to handle input from. As the Win32 API is responsible for window management, yes you can't get around using the Win32 API. Else, how would you create a window for your context?

In cases where a cross-platform GUI library is used for window management like Qt, GTK etc., you still need to extract a HWND handle for your window from these libraries as the D3D11 API operates on Win32 window handles (HWND) and again at this point, you are using the Win32 API.

Comment: Already answered on [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0840a810-7fa7-4a53-8f14-a4a0e6dde858/are-these-functions-and-parameters-used-in-directx-112?forum=wingameswithdirectx)